# Unable to search string in json_query ansible module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, I have output and am trying to fail/pass based on existence of a string in the json response that am getting. any hint?

```
      - name: "Fetch all gpu/dgx nodes from clusters using K8s facts"
        k8s_facts:
          kubeconfig: $WORKSPACE
          kind: Node
          label_selectors:
          - nodeType=gpu
          verify_ssl: no
        register: node_list

      - debug:
          var: node_list
      - debug:
          var: node_list | json_query(query)
        vars:
          query: 'resources[].{node_name: metadata.name, nodeType: metadata.labels.nodeType}'
        failed_when: '"gpu" not in query.results'
```

````
TASK [2_k8s_validations : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "node_list | json_query(query)": [
        {
            "nodeType": "gpu",
            "node_name": "dgx"
        },
        {
            "nodeType": "gpu",
            "node_name": "dgx"
        }
    ]
}```
````

TASK [2_k8s_validations : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '\"gpu\" not in query.results' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (\"gpu\" not in query.results): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if \"gpu\" not in query.results %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'AnsibleUndefined' is not iterable"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************
target1                    : ok=10   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: Separately, `debug: var:` is for **variables** but `node_list | json_query(query)` is not a _variable_ it's an _expression_; it's a damn miracle that ansible more-or-less did what you asked, but I wouldn't get into the habit of counting on that, since it is likely undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding; `vars:` only declares "local" variables for the current task. Since you just declared a variable named `query`, and that variable is not a `dict`, then it has no such child property `.results`

Very likely you want to use [`set_fact:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/set_fact_module.html) to assert a new ansible fact into the `hostvars` structure, so you can then use it like you attempted to do:

```
  - set_fact:
      nodes_with_node_type: '{{ node_list | json_query(query) }}'
    vars:
      query: 'resources[].{node_name: metadata.name, nodeType: metadata.labels.nodeType}'

  - fail:
      msg: Expected to find at least one GPU node type
    vars:
      node_types: '{{ nodes_with_node_type | map(attribute="nodeType") | list }}'
    when: '"gpu" not in node_types'
```

---

Separate from your specific question, the actual task you are trying to accomplish is utter nonsense, given that your selector on the `k8s_facts:` explicitly asks for `nodeType=gpu` -- there will not be any other kinds of Nodes that are returned and thus the `when:` will never be true

Comment: thanks, the reason to check for when: was in terms of response [success/failure] and also, that gpu nodes exists, coz sometimes they are just lost so not literally only for a string compare am using when:. do you suggest any other way if i made sense now?

Comment: Also: am learning this, but can you possible post a looping solution to this where I can loop over only the values of the keys and then ssh them? below is my question.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498378/ansible-ssh-to-json-query-response-values-in-loop/58501003#58501003`