# ansible ssh to json_query response values in loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team, I have response from json_query which is a dict key:value and i would like to iterate over all values and run ssh command for each value

Below gets me list of all nodes

```
- name: "Fetch all nodes from clusters using K8s facts"
k8s_facts:
  kubeconfig: $WORKSPACE
  kind: Node
  verify_ssl: no
register: node_list

- debug:
  var: node_list | json_query(query)
vars:
  query: 'resources[].{node_name: metadata.name, nodeType: metadata.labels.nodeType}'
```

## TASK [3_validations_on_ssh : debug]

```
ok: [target1] => {
    "node_list | json_query(query)": [
        {
            "nodeType": null,
            "node_name": "host1"
        },
        {
            "nodeType": "gpu",
            "node_name": "host2"
        },
        {
            "nodeType": "gpu",
            "node_name": "host3"
        }
    ]
}
```

playbook to write: parse node_name and use that in ssh command for all hosts 1-3

```
- name: "Loop on all nodeNames and ssh."
shell: ssh -F ~/.ssh/ssh_config bouncer@{{ item }}.internal.sshproxy.net "name -a"
register: ssh_result_per_host
failed_when: ssh_result_per_host.rc != 0
with_item: {{ for items in query.node_name }}
- debug:
  var: ssh_result_per_host.stdout_lines
```

## error output:

```
> The offending line appears to be:
        failed_when: ssh_result_per_host.rc != 0
        with_item: {{ for items in query.node_name }}
                    ^ here
```

solution 2 also fails when i do loop:

```
          shell: ssh -F ~/.ssh/ssh_config bouncer@{{ item.metadata.name }}.sshproxy.internal.net "name -a"
        loop: "{{ node_list.resources }}"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.metadata.name }}"
```

output sol 2:

```
failed: [target1] (item=host1) => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: shell"}
failed: [target1] (item=host2) => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: shell"}
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "All items completed"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Ash's correct answer:

```
  - name: "Fetch all nodes from clusters using K8s facts"
    k8s_facts:
      kubeconfig: $WORKSPACE
      kind: Node
      verify_ssl: no
    register: node_list

  - set_fact:
      k8s_node_names: '{{ node_list | json_query(query) | map(attribute="node_name") | list }}'
    vars:
      query: 'resources[].{node_name: metadata.name, nodeType: metadata.labels.nodeType}'

  - name: "Loop on all nodeNames and ssh."
    shell: ssh -F ~/.ssh/ssh_config bouncer@{{ item }}.internal.sshproxy.net "name -a"
    register: ssh_result_per_host
    with_items: '{{ k8s_node_names }}'
```

---

Separately, unless you quite literally just want to run that *one* `ssh` command, the way ansible thinks about that problem is via [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/add_host_module.html):

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  # ... as before, to generate the  "k8s_node_names" list
  - add_host:
      hostname: '{{ item }}.internal.sshproxy.net'
      groups:
      - the_k8s_nodes
      ansible_ssh_username: bouncer
      # whatever other per-host variables you want
    with_items: '{{ k8s_node_names }}'

# now, run the playbook against those nodes
- hosts: the_k8s_nodes
  tasks:
  - name: run "name -a" on the host
    command: name -a
    register: whatever
```

This is a contrived example, because if you actually wanted just to get the list of kubernetes nodes and use those in a playbook, you use would [a dynamic inventory script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. this was super. I just tried 1st sol and will try 2nd next.

Comment: I have a followup to this: how can i map multiple attributes? like
``` k8s_node_names: '{{ node_list | json_query(query) | map(attribute=("node_name", "nodeType")) | list }}'```

Answer (score 0):

It is not `with_item` it is `with_items`
You cannot use `with_item: {{ for items in query.node_name }}`
Save the values to a variable and use the variable in `with_items: {{ new_variable }}`

Comment: But it’s a dictionary how can I save just the values as a list to a variable ? Would you please mind giving complete syntax, meanwhile I try.